# Как можно получить все A записи в DNS ?

Tags: dns, linux

Как можно получить все А записи для определенного домена через запрос к ДНС ?

Comment: с поддоменами?

Comment: Что-то мне подсказывает, что с поддоменами никак. Т.к. по сути, любой поддомен - это полноценный домен.

Comment: очень часто AXFT открыт

Comment: Спасибо, про AXFR я как-то даже не подумал

Answer (score 2, accepted):

командой [dig](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dig) например:

```
dig -t any google.com
```

Comment: Спасибо, про any я как-то и не вспомнил совсем